# JavaScript Fetch with method "POST" is called twice

Tags: javascript, java, spring, post

As part of a project I'm doing, I wrote a spring framework application server in Java. 
I now want to write a client for it using JavaScript using webpack.
In one of my files I call fetch with POST method, but for some reason, it's called twice and my server throws an exception (because it tries to put the same object with the same key in the database)
I thought it had something to do with CORS, so I enabled added a WebConfig file to my server from a source I found on this website.
But, unfortunately, it still occurs and I don't know why.

my js file with the fetch:

```
const button = document.getElementById('register');
const url = "http://localhost:8083/playground/users";
let form;

button.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  form = {
    email: document.getElementById("email").value,
    username: document.getElementById("username").value,
    avatar: document.getElementById("avatar").value,
    role: "Guest"
  };

  const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(form),
          });

  const resultJson = await response.json();
  console.log(resultJson);
  //location.href='./confirm.html';
});
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const JS_JSX_PATTERN = /\.jsx?$/;

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'src/index.html'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'confirm.html',
      template: 'src/confirm.html',
      chunks: []
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: JS_JSX_PATTERN,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './',
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000
    }
  }
};
```

and the result of invoking the fetch makes it be called twice, as can be seen here:
[image]

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have a script tag with src of "bundle.js" in the head of your HTML file?

Comment: Why does it fail on the first, not the second call?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I have a script tag, but it's in my body, does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be due to incorrect bundle path try to use path.resolve("your output directrory")

```
....
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
...
```

Comment: You, my friend, are a great man. That actually was my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a custom `HtmlWebpackPlugin` template -- do you have a script tag pointing to `./bundle.js` in that `src/index.html` by any chance?

`HtmlWebpackPlugin` is meant to add bundle script for you automatically. Looking at the screenshot, I'm guessing the `VM....bundle.js` is the one served from memory by `webpack-dev-server`, and the 2nd `bunde.js` is the one you created locally in previous `webpack build`.